# symfony2 generator timeout?

Tags: php, console, timeout, generator, symfony

I have timeout problems with the symfony2 app/console generator.

**As Example:**

If I want to generate a new Bundle and type in

```
php app/console generate:bundle
```

I have about 20 seconds until a "Killed" message stops the whole process. Seems like a timeout, but how can I change/disable it? 20 seconds might sound long, but it takes about 20 seconds to read the instructions and question, and another 20 to answer the first one.

Its confusing...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's about Symfony2, 
can you try this?

```
php -r "sleep(25);"
```

If the "Killed" message appear, Symfony2 is ok.

Then try this:

```
sleep 25
```

If you have again the "Killed" error, your issue is a system one, maybe your adminsys have applied some restrictions.

Are you reaching the server via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning up the `max_execution_time` and/or `max_input_time` in your `php.ini`... So you'll have some more time to generate your bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this couldn't be the problem: max_execution_time is 55s and max_input_time is -1 (default value).